# The jQuery :eq(index) selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to use the jQuery :eq(index) selector dynamically, which means I want to supply a variable as the index and choose the corresponding element dynamically. But it seems that it doesn't work. I think it's because the quotation marks. As this selector is used as, for example, $('ul li:eq(3)'), when I provide a variable as the index, maybe the index is viewed as a part of the string in the selector instead of a variable. Is it right? How can I fix this and choose the element dynamically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var index = 5;
```

The following would work in your example.

```
$('ul li:eq(' + index + ')')
```

But for better performance in modern browsers, use:

```
$('ul li').eq(index)
```

Another reason `.eq()` is better than `:eq()` is you can pass '.eq(-1)' to get the last element.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Answer (score 3):

Your suspicions are correct, a variable name inside a string is treated as part of the string, not a variable name. You want to use string concatenation to let Javascript know your variable is a variable. It would look like this:

```
$('ul li:eq(' + myVar + ')')
```

Now, `myVar` is being recognized as a variable, not as part of the string.

Comment: Thx, man. One more question, how could I check in firebug if I select the right element? I want to console.log the element selected by jQuery selector, but it always shows [object Object] in firebug console panel. How could I see the real element I selected?

Comment: Do: `console.log($('ul li').eq(index))`.

Comment: Use `console.log($('ul li:eq(' + myVar + ')')[0])` to get the HTML element out of the jQuery object (which is what you are currently logging).

Comment: By the way, Chrome's built in console rules.

Comment: @iambriansreed: I couldn't agree more. :) Love Chrome's console.

Comment: @iambriansreed your method doesn't work. I don't know if it's because firebug or there is sth wrong with my syntax. Here is my code($(self.el) is the current li element): console.log('li: '+$(self.el).closest('ul').children().eq(position));

Comment: @ElliotBonneville it just show [object HTMLLIElement].But I want to see the dom element and all its content. Is it possible?

Comment: Then stop appending strings to the object or the object can't print nicely.

Comment: Not: console.log('li: '+$(self.el).closest('ul').children().eq(position));

Comment: Use this instead: `console.log($(self.el).closest('ul').children().eq(position))` You can't append a string and view an object in the same `console.log` call.

Comment: @chaonextdoor Nice to see you went with my suggestion. `.eq()` vs `:eq()`.

Comment: No problem. If this answer was at all helpful to you, please upvote it. If it solved your problem, would you be kind enough to mark it as the solution? (via the checkmark next to it)

Comment: @iambriansreed it seems that .eq() is more convenient and there is no need to use string concatenation. Thx for your suggestion.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest accepting Brian's answer as it appears to have proven more helpful to you. :)